# Scrolling property for body part of the table not working

Tags: html, css, scroll, html-table

I have a table in which headers should be fixed at their positions and scrolling content.

I found way to scroll them by making first headeing using by a sepparate tables, and body part using a second table which is inside a div which is given scroll property.

But when the number of columns are getting increased, alligning the headings in first table and content in second table is getting difficult.

Thats why I am forced to create a scroll in tbody. But it is not working. I tried to give scroll property to the tbody part and fixed its height, but it is not scrolling.

The code which I am trying to correct is,

```
<table width="900" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th scope="col">h1</th>
    <th scope="col">h2</th>
    <th scope="col">h3</th>
    <th scope="col">h4</th>
    <th scope="col">h5</th>
    <th scope="col">h6</th>
  </tr>
  </thead>

   <tbody style="height:5px; overflow:scroll;">
  <tr>
    <td height="10">1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>6</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td height="10">7</td>
    <td>8</td>
    <td>9</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td height="10">3</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>7</td>
    <td>8</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td height="10">9</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
  </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

And the code which creates fixed headers using 2 tables is

```
<table width="900" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th scope="col">h1</th>
    <th scope="col">h2</th>
    <th scope="col">h3</th>
    <th scope="col">h4</th>
    <th scope="col">h5</th>
    <th scope="col">h6</th>
  </tr>
  </thead>
  </table>
 <div  style="height:50px; overflow-y:scroll; width:920px;">
<table width="900" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tr>
    <td height="10">1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>6</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td height="10">7</td>
    <td>8</td>
    <td>9</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td height="10">3</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>7</td>
    <td>8</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td height="10">9</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

try it like this

```
<table width="900" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
 <thead>
  <tr>
    <th scope="col">h1</th>
    <th scope="col">h2</th>
    <th scope="col">h3</th>
    <th scope="col">h4</th>
    <th scope="col">h5</th>
    <th scope="col">h6</th>
  </tr>
  </thead>

<tbody>
<tr>
  <td height="10" colspan="6">
    <div style="height:5px; overflow:scroll;">
        <!--put your new table here (content of tbody)-->

    </div>
</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Thanks for considering this question, I tried your answer, but it produces some what the similer table as I specified I obtained. Here also header and body llignments are not same

Comment: what do you exactly want? you want that your tbody content should be scrollable?

Comment: I am trying to scroll the tbody part as in first set of codes.. 
The code in second set is working, but while adding more rows, for example 40- the allignments become difficult... Thats y I am trying to apply scroll for the same table

Comment: use CSS to have full control on your table behavior, it will be easy to manage them.